# Understanding the CAF actor function which returns void

Tags: c++, c++-actor-framework

I know actors can be implemented by function. The following code snippet is from CAF github examples/[hello_world.cpp](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/master/examples/hello_world.cpp).

I know the first one implementation method, which binds a couple of message handlers to the actor. The actor will be alive at background and triggered by events, then terminated when `self->quit` is called.

But the second one returns nothing, where is its message handler? And it looks like no any `self->quit`-like function to terminate itself. Is it alive when hello_world returns? Or it just terminate itself after finished the response in `then`?

```
behavior mirror(event_based_actor* self) {  
    return {
        [=](const string& what) { ... } 
        [=](int) { ...}            
    }
};

void hello_world(event_based_actor* self, const actor& buddy) {  
    self->sync_send(...).then(
        ...
    );
}

int main() {  
    auto mirror_actor = spawn(mirror); 
    spawn(hello_world, mirror_actor);                
    await_all_actors_done();
    shutdown();
}
```

Updated,

Actor will terminate itself if non of message handlers in its behavior stack.

Even `hello_word` returns nothing as actor's listening behavior. The actor is still alive when function returns. Because the `sync_send` has added the `then-behavior` in stack to prepare the responding from mirror. After the one-shot `then-behavior` is popped up to finish the response, stack is empty then actor is right to terminate itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the second one returns nothing, where is its message handler? And it looks like no any `self->quit`-like function to terminate itself. Is it alive when `hello_world` returns? Or it just terminate itself after finished the response in then?

Since the function `hello_world` returns void and not `behavior`, the actor executing this function automatically terminates once it reaches the end of the function. This actor performs three actions after being spawned:

1. Send a message via `sync_send`.
2. Wait for the corresponding response.
3. Terminate.

Comment: Can I say that "The `sync_send(...).then( ONE_SHOT_HANDLER )` call is not blocking and add a one-shot-handler on actor's behavior stack. So the actor will run at background and stay alive even reached the end of the `hello_world` function `UNTIL` the response sent back to trigger/pop up the one-shot-handler. Then the actor terminate itself due to empty behavior stack." ?

Comment: I've done a simple test. The hello_world actor is able to respond mirror replies(I put a sleeping for 3 second in mirror) even the end of hello_world function has already been reached. Then after finished the response, the await_all_actors_done() is un-blocked.

Comment: In general, your mental model appears correct. The function `await_all_other_actors_done()` blocks until all actors have terminated. Note that when you put it sleep in an actor, it will block the runtime, which has an effect on all voluntarily scheduled actors.

Comment: Is the `no behavior in stack` one of conditions that makes actor to terminate itself?

Comment: Correct. In particular, if the actor is initialized but has no behavior on its stack, and the runtime transfers control into the actor, then the actor is considered "done" and terminates.

Comment: This helps me a lot to understand about the lifetime of Actor. Thanks.